# Only admin can subscribe, add to cart

Tags: uri

Helllllloooo guys my website is having weird problem as only admin can subscribe in webform news letter subscription , click to add cart in ubercart, but it's not possible for normal anonymous users or any other roles,  even anonymous users can't register. Actually problem persist to every subscribe type button. My website name is www.f-trend.com.

Comment: Are you suer that under /admin/people/permissions everything is the way you wanted it to be?

Comment: When I try to subscribe with email and no required name form does not give validation feedback. I think you have some other issues you are unaware off. It is more than permissios.

Comment: I am really not able to get clue what is happening wrong, only admin can subscribe or add to cart.

Comment: @DhruvaTripathi And can you please answer my question from the first comment here? Providing clarifications and additional data will get you more responses than repeating that you're clueless. I didn't ask for fun, I ask because it (maybe) will help to find a reason of your problem.

Comment: @molot sir sorry for forgetting to reply you. After your suggestion I have checked everything in permission area buy seems everything is OK, I feel some modules are creating problems. I see problem arise whenever there is a submit buttons rest links are perfectly working

Comment: As I said only admins can subscribe to ubercart, even anonymous users can't register as next page is not getting shown to them  problems are with all the roles except admin

Comment: Thanks for all efforts from you guys, finally I was able to get solution after deleting last installed modules, like bean, gd infinite scroll, pagination 3000,global expose filter. They were causing an issue.